# PHP memcached - igbinary_serialize_serialize in Unknown on line 0

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Recently upgraded PHP to PHP 7.2 on ubuntu-1616.04 and ran into the following error message while execute any php command for example:

`php -v`

ERROR:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so: undefined symbol: igbinary_serialize), /usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

[image]

COULD YOU HELPME?

Tnaks

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old question, but I stumbled upon the same error.

You might be missing igbinary

Install it with:

```
apt-get install php-igbinary
```

(You may need to use php7.X-igbinary, depending on your version)

My installation was also missing msgpack, which I installed as well:

```
apt-get install php-msgpack
```